# Changing select options based on a previous select's value with JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm wanting to change the options in my second select drop down based off of what I have selected in my first select drop down. I've done this with regular old JS, but I wanted a better way of doing it in JQM.

I have an object with all the options, like this:

```
var options = {
    blah1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    blah2: ["D", "E", "F"],
    blah3: ["G", "G", "I"]
};
```

I have these select inputs:

```
<select value="firstSelect">
    <option value="blah1">Blah1</option>
    <option value="blah2">Blah2</option>
    <option value="blah3">Blah3</option>
</select>

<select value="secondSelect">
</select>
```

Here is what I currently have in my main.JS:

```
$('#firstSelect').change(function() {
    var x= $('#secondSelect').val()
    for(index in options[x]) {
        $('#secondSelect').append('<option value="' + options[x][index] + '">' + options[x][index] + '</option>')
    };
});
```

When blah1 is selected in the first select drop down, the second select drop down would be populated with options.blah1 values. Then the same with blah2 and blah3. That is the idea I'm trying to get working.

I had a similar version of this working without using JQM, but now I can't figure it out.
Can anyone help get this working?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I figured it out! I needed to add `$('#secondSelect').selectmenu('refresh', true);` at the end, before closing out the whole block. It was working, I just needed to refresh the second select drop down to update it. Hope this helps someone.

By the way, I can't answer my own question, so I just added this edit. Anyone can feel free to answer.

Comment: `value="Blah1"` should be lowercase, like your javascript property names.

Comment: I'm sorry, I typed this out really fast, but they are the same on the actual product.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you named a lot of things incorrectly.
You used `value` instead of `id` in your HTML.
You got the `val()` of `secondSelect` instead of `firstSelect`.

HTML

```
<select id="firstSelect">
<option value="blah1">Blah1</option>
<option value="blah2">Blah2</option>
<option value="blah3">Blah3</option>
</select>

<select id="secondSelect">
</select>​
```

Javascript

```
var options = {
    blah1: ["A", "B", "C"],
    blah2: ["D", "E", "F"],
    blah3: ["G", "G", "I"]
};

$(function() {
    $('#firstSelect').change(function() {
        var x = $('#firstSelect').val()
        for (var index in options[x]) {
            $('#secondSelect').append('<option value="' + options[x][index] + '">' + options[x][index] + '</option>')
        };
    });
});​
```

Comment: Oops, you are right. I did put secondSelect instead of firstSelect. And Rafael spotted my lack of ids, also. I meant to have them in there. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that are some errors in you code...

1. First, your select elements don't have ID attribute, you insert the "ids" into a attribute named value
2. Second, in your javascript function, you're trying to get selected value from select1 in a wrong way... the correct form would be `$('#firstSelect :selected').val()`
3. Last one, when you use `.append()` method you don't clean the old html, so, you must use `.html("")` before use the `.append()` method...

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZhQ8/) with a functional example.

Comment: Yeah, I messed up on the ids, but I have them in my actual code.

Also, I ran into the third issue right after. That would, indeed, work, but I used this:
    $('#type').find("option").remove()
I popped it in right before my for statement.