# Set option based on previous select option for a dynamically created table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the values of 2 select tags based on a conditional value set beforehand (also a select tag) on multiple table rows.

I achieved it using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304728/changing-select-options-based-on-a-previous-selects-value-with-jqm). However, seeing as how only the first row is hard-coded; the rest are dynamically created using an add row function, only the first row is handled by the latter script.

My aim is to emulate the functionality of the first row (i.e change `append w_cars, w_driver, d_cars, d_drivers to #car1, #driver1 when #water_type is changed respectively` on all rows).

I tried playing around with the positioning of the aforementioned script with no result. Due to issues retaining my implementation of a the back-end (Flask) I was forced into having both hard-coded and dynamic rows.

I have included the full relevant code snippet; the tags in question are `#car1`, `#driver1`, `#water_type`.

```js
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add_sales').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery(' <tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price1"></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q1"></td><td> <select class="form-control" name="car1" id="car1"> </select></td><td> <select class="form-control" name="driver1" id="driver1">  </select></td><td><select class="form-control" name="water_type"><option value="w">w</option><option value="d">d</option></select></td><td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="client1"></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.daily_list').append(newRow);
    document.getElementById("counter").value = counter;
});

var options = {
    w_cars: ["102", "103", "104", '106'],
    w_driver: ["Mouse", "Cat", "Jerry", "Tom"],
    d_cars: ["H-101", "H-102", "H-103"],
    d_driver: ["Apple", "Lemon"]
};

$(function(){
    $('#water_type').change(function() {
        var x= $('#water_type :selected').val();
        var driver = x + "_driver"
        $('#driver1').html("");
        for(index in options[driver]) {
            $('#driver1').append('<option value="' + options[driver][index] + '">' + options[driver][index] + '</option>')
        };
    });

    $('#water_type').change(function() {
        var x= $('#water_type :selected').val();
        var car = x + "_cars"
        $('#car1').html("");
        for(index in options[car]) {
            $('#car1').append('<option value="' + options[car][index] + '">' + options[car][index] + '</option>')
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="taskTable" class="daily_list table table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Q</th>
    <th>Car</th>
    <th>Driver</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Client</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='price1'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='q1'>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="car1" id='car1'>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="driver1" id='driver1'>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="water_type" name="water_type">
          <option value="w">w</option>
          <option value="d">d</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name='client1'>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <input id='counter' type='hidden' value="" name='counter'>
  </tbody>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>date</label>
      <input id="date" class="form-control" type="date" name='date'>
    </div>
    <a class="add_sales btn btn-success btn-fill pull-right" href="#">Add Row</a>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</table>
```

Comment: Realized that `id` must be unique, appended `counter` to the id string to make each row unique. Same result; only works on the first row. https://jsfiddle.net/pttLysky/1/

Comment: Resolved the issue by duplicating the select function and placing it inside the add row function. Not the prettiest answer; wont mark as answered though, seems hectic; there should an much more cleaner way. https://jsfiddle.net/pttLysky/4/